# Create Qt windows based on number of list items

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

first of all, this is my code:

```
class Fillscreen(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_View):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent,)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def full(self):
        self.showMaximized()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    monitors = selector.getMonitors()
    resolutions = selector.getResolution(monitors)
    for monitor in monitors:
        window = Fillscreen()
        window.move(monitor[0],monitor[1])
        window.full()
    app.exec_()
```

`monitors` looks like this:
`[(-1280, 0, 0, 1024), (0, 0, 1920, 1080), (1920, 0, 3840, 1080)]`

As is it only creates one window, which absolutely makes sense since im overwriting `window` on each loop.
To solve this i could manually create a `window1`, `window2` and `window3`

But how would i do this when i can't be sure of the Number of Monitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`QApplication::desktop()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#desktop):

```
...

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ws = []

    for i in range(QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenCount()):
        topLeft = QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry(i).topLeft()
        window = Fillscreen()
        window.move(topLeft)
        window.full()
        ws.append(window)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes my code easier to determine the number of screens + coordinates but doesn't solve my general Problem of creating X number of windows. The given Code does only create one window aswell.

Comment: The variables created within a loop have the scope of the loop so they are eliminated except the last, so use the list to save the data since it has a larger scope. :)